# React AG Grid processDataFromClipboard raising issue

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid-react

while using `processDataFromClipboard` If I copy empty data and paste on React AG Grid then the whole grid styles behave malfunction and it moves up around 400px, and if I remove `processDataFromClipboard` from grid it works fine. It also shows error like

> clipboardGridData.forEach is malfunction